# When a dialog that is bound to a datagrid cell is cancelled how to revert the bound data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular with angular ui-grid and angular-modal-service + bootstrap.

The data in my ui-grid is also bound to my dialog which opens when the user double-clicks into the datagrid`s cell.

When the user changes data in the dialog it is also changed in the datagrid.

When the user decides to cancel the dialog the edited data remains in the cell

thanks to databinding...

Is there any feature in angularJS which can give me more control when databind should start/end or how to intercept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common approach (prior to Angular 1.3) was to make a copy of the object before passing it to the dialog. When the user saves the edit, you replace the original w/the edited copy.

In Angular 1.3 they added [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) which gives you finer control of when the model value is updated.  When you use ng-model, it stores the data in two properties named `viewValue` and `modelValue`.

`viewValue` is what is currently in typed into the input/text area. `modelValue` is the actual value used by the binding, and it may not match `viewValue` if the user enters something invalid.

With `ng-model-options` you can defer updating the model value until some event occurs. In this case, you can use the "submit" event dispatched by the form to delay updating the model:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" ng-submit="onFormSubmit()">
  <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="dialogData.value" />
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="cancelDialog()">Cancel</button>
</form>

$scope.onFormSubmit = function() {
  // do something then close dialog
  $scope.$close();
};

$scope.cancelDialog = function() {
  // cancel any pending updates to modelValue
  // not required in this example, but good practice
  $scope.myForm.$rollbackViewValue();
  $scope.$close();
}
```

Link to an [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZBir6?p=preview).

This works well in scenarios where you throw away the form (like one inside of modal dialog). But I've had some trouble with validations, which I believe is just an Angular bug, b/c the [documentation for $rollbackViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#rollbackViewValue) mentions using it to reset a form.